# Change chartType onclick ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, chart.js

So I have made a chart with ChartJS, but I want to change the chartType from 'line' to 'bar' on a button click.

I've tried something like this:

```
let chartType = 'line';
function click() {
  chartType = 'bar';
}
```

Underneath I just paste this:

```
type: chartType,
data: donationChartBuilder,
etc
```

But this is not updating my chart on my button click? 
I've set up the button correctly:

```
... onclick="click()" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global variable to instance the chart object and work on it with your javascript, here you have an example here with 3 buttons, one per type

```html
<button onclick="draw_line()">Line</button>
<button onclick="draw_bar()">Bar</button>
<button onclick="draw_pie()">Pie</button>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var chart;
    var types = ['line', 'bar', 'pie'];
    var current_type = 0;
    draw_initial();
    
    function switch_type(){
      if(current_type++ == types.length-1) current_type = 0;
      switch(current_type){
        case 0: draw_line(); break;
        case 1: draw_bar(); break;
        case 2: draw_pie(); break;
      }
    }
    
    function draw_pie() {
       if(chart) chart.destroy(); // Check if chart object exists and if it exists, destroy it.
    
    /* Generating random data and colors */
    
    var data_colors = [
        'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
    ];
    var data_values = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
    ];
     
     /* Creating the new chart */
     
     var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'pie',
    
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: data_colors,
                borderColor: data_colors,
                data: data_values
            }]
        },
    
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
    }
    
    
    function draw_bar() {    
    if(chart) chart.destroy(); // Check if chart object exists and if it exists, destroy it.
    
    /* Generating random data and colors */
    
    var data_colors = 'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')';
    var data_values = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
    ];
         
     /* Creating the new chart */
     
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'bar',
    
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: data_colors,
                borderColor: data_colors,
                data: data_values
            }]
        },
    
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
    }
    
    function draw_line() {
   if(chart) chart.destroy(); // Check if chart object exists and if it exists, destroy it.
    
    /* Generating random data and colors */
    
     var data_colors = 'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')';
    var data_values = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
    ];
         
     /* Creating the new chart */
     
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',
    
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: data_colors,
                borderColor: data_colors,
                data: data_values
            }]
        },
    
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
    }
    
    function draw_initial() {
    draw_line();
    }
    </script>
```

You have to remember to instance the destroy function of the chart object before reload it to change its tipe.

### Update

If you want to use only one button you can use the same logic, but with the type of the chart, in this example I added a global variable containing an array with all available types, but you can do it as you need.

```html
<button onclick="switch_type()"> Change type </button>
<span style="margin-left:10px">Hi, I'm a 
    
    <span id="chart-type"></span> chart :)

</span>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var chart;
    var types = ['line', 'bar', 'pie'];
    var current_type = 0;
    draw_initial();
    
    function switch_type(){
      if(current_type++ == types.length-1) current_type = 0;
      switch(current_type){
        case 0: draw_line(); break;
        case 1: draw_bar(); break;
        case 2: draw_pie(); break;
      }
    }
    
    function draw_pie() {
       if(chart) chart.destroy(); // Check if chart object exists and if it exists, destroy it.
    
    /* Generating random data and colors */
    
    var data_colors = [
        'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
      'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')',
    ];
    var data_values = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
    ];

     $("#chart-type").html("pie"); // Adding some info
     
     /* Creating the new chart */
     
     var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'pie',
    
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: data_colors,
                borderColor: data_colors,
                data: data_values
            }]
        },
    
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
    }
    
    
    function draw_bar() {    
    if(chart) chart.destroy(); // Check if chart object exists and if it exists, destroy it.
    
    /* Generating random data and colors */
    
     var data_colors = 'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')';
    var data_values = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
    ];
    
     $("#chart-type").html("bar"); // Adding some info
     
     /* Creating the new chart */
     
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'bar',
    
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: data_colors,
                borderColor: data_colors,
                data: data_values
            }]
        },
    
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
    }
    
    function draw_line() {
   if(chart) chart.destroy(); // Check if chart object exists and if it exists, destroy it.
    
    /* Generating random data and colors */
    
     var data_colors = 'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() *150)+75)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() *200)+25)+')';
    var data_values = [
        Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
      Math.floor(Math.random() *100),
    ];
    
     $("#chart-type").html("line"); // Adding some info
     
     /* Creating the new chart */
     
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',
    
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: data_colors,
                borderColor: data_colors,
                data: data_values
            }]
        },
    
        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
    }
    
    function draw_initial() {
    draw_line();
    }
    </script>
```